# LXD - How to execute a script inside a container from host

Tags: bash, lxd

I wrote a github pull script inside the running container so that the container can get the updated codes.
But how can I call this script from the host machine?

I have tried with something like this but with no success.

```
lxc exec container-name -- gitPull.sh
lxc exec container-name --sh -c "cd ~ && ll"
```

I have also tried to push a directory from host to lxd containers, but it won't copy the sub directory into the container.

Could any one help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you run `lxc exec` on an Ubuntu container, you get a root shell and your home directory is `/root`.

If you are using a non-root account (like `ubuntu` from `ubuntu:18.04`), then you can get a shell into that account with

```
lxc exec mycontainer -- sudo --login --user ubuntu
```

And if you want to run a command as user `ubuntu`, then you can

```
$ lxc exec mycontainer -- sudo --login --user ubuntu whoami
ubuntu
```

You have a typo in `lxc exec container-name --sh -c "cd ~ && ll"`. There should be a space after `--` because `--` is a special instruction to your host's shell which says that the `lxc exec` command should stop reading any subsequent options as options for `lxc exec`. For example, the following is wrong, because the `-l` option is processed by `lxc exec` instead of being given verbatim as a command to run in the container.

```
$ lxc exec mycontainer ls -l
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'l' in -l
```

The correct would be

```
$ lxc exec mycontainer -- ls -l
```

You can push a directory from the host to the container by running

```
$ lxc file push --recursive /home/myusername/myfiles/ mycontainer/home/ubuntu/
```

The directory tree `/home/myusername/myfiles/` on the host will get copied into the container `mycontainer` inside the (existing) directory `/home/ubuntu/` (in that container).